# Productivity Powertools 2015 features stopped working after restoring VS2015 to factory settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, productivity-power-tools

I recently restored my VS2015 settings back to factory settings and the following features of Productivity Powertools 2015 stopped working:

Format document on save
Remove and Sort Usings on save

In Options > Productivity Power Tools > PowerCommands they are both enabled.

Anyone know what I can do to restore this functionality? I lost it after restoring my VS2015 to factory settings.

Comment: Do you have tried to uninstall Powertools and reinstall them?

Comment: @IgorDamiani yes and still doesn't work. I am about to completely uninstall VS2015